# Proportional Segment

Tags: geometry

> In the attached figure, a homotecia of ratio -0.6 and center O (0, m)
>   transforms the horizontal segment FS, in segment PQ. If P and S are on
>   the vertical axis, both to five units of the X-axis, then the value of
>   m is:

[image]

I cant resolve this, in the guide the alternatives are:

```
a) 3/5
b) 3
c) 2
d) 5/3
e) 5/4
```

I understand that the `PO` segment would be `(5 - m)`
And the segment `FS` would be `(5 + m)`

**But i cant resolve that...**

Answer (score 0):

$$
{PO\over OS}=0.6,
$$
hence:
$$
{5-m\over5+m}=0.6
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
m={5\over4}.
$$

Comment: Incorrect, because 0.6 is the hometecia

Comment: Incorrect? What is your definition of  homothety? With the usual definition, $P$ is the image of $S$, and $O$ is the center, so $PO/SO=0.6$.

Comment: right, you recently edited the answer, thanks Aretino,
That was my answer before I asked here, but how can I prove it? Why if you realize, more than one alternative is correcti do (5+m) + (5-m)*0.6 = 10

Comment: There is nothing to prove: it is the definition of homothety, which once again I urge you to look up. And I don't see any other correct alternatives.

Comment: Oh thanks aretino, sorry for my bad knowledge :(